# Pass variable instead of quoted string into boto3 ec2 client command

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

What specific changes need to be made to the below in order to pass variables into the "Filters" argument of the `boto3 ec2` client request below?

```
def getRtbId(vpcId,nameTag):
    client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')

    response = client.describe_route_tables(
        Filters=[
            {'Name': 'vpc-id','Values': [\'vpcId\']},
            {'Name': 'tag:Name','Values': [\'nameTag\']}
        ]
    )
```

The values for `vpcId` and `nameTag` only work when they are entered as literal strings.  But the problem is that, as you can see, the values must be passed into the command as variables.  Every syntax that we have tried to pass in the `vpcId` and `nameTag` values as variables has resulted in one of a number of different un-helpful syntax errors.

The documentation is at [this link](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_route_tables), but the documentation does not seem to be helpful for this question.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: Probably `[vpcId]` and `[nameTag]`

Comment: @B.Gees That makes no sense, what are you concatenating to?

Comment: This is basic Python, not really anything to do with boto3. You're passing an array of filters (Filters=[...]). Each filter is a dict ({...}), and each dict contains the key 'Name' (with an associated value that is a string) and the key 'Values' (with an associated value that is a list of strings). If you have variables named id and email, then a list containing them is [id, email]. In your case, a list containing vpcId is [vpcId]. Similarly for nameTag.

Comment: @jarmod That is helpful.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put quotes into the argument. Quotes are part of the syntax of string literals, they're not part of the data. If you want to get the value from a variable, just put the variable there.

```
    response = client.describe_route_tables(
        Filters=[
            {'Name': 'vpc-id','Values': [vpcId]},
            {'Name': 'tag:Name','Values': [nameTag]}
        ]
    )
```